# Mysql: Update all rows with the same name with a single id

Tags: mysql

I have a table in with a unique id column, a non-unique name column, and other irrelevant columns. I want to update rows of data based off a single id. I've tried:

`UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'blah' WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = 1613)`

But that gives this error `Table 'mytable' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`

Then I tried:

`UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'blah' WHERE name IN (SELECT name WHERE id = 1613)`

The problem with this is that it is only affecting 1 row, even though there are multiple rows that have the same name.

I know how to accomplish this by using 2 different queries. One to fetch the name, and the other to update rows using that name. But is there a way to do this with just 1 query?

Comment: I am not clear why you are using in here - surely = would do - nb- not the solution to your problem jus a request for clarification.

Comment: I assumed = would give an error if the subquery returned more than 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join tables to update them :

```
UPDATE mytable t1 inner join mytable t2 on t1.name = t2.name SET t1.myfield = 'blah'  where t2.id = 1613
```

Comment: Nope it update all rows with same name as 1613

Answer (score 0):

When you try to update the same table as you a re getting the right amount of rows, the result set can change every row that is updated. that is not possible.

solution make a temporary table as below

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'blah' WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) t1 WHERE id = 1613)
```

Comment: The explanation is good, thanks. That query still only affected 1 row though.

Comment: this here is the same as the accepted answer. show me data where this doesn't work. iNNER JOIN and the where IN a iterchangable, only that the IN Clause can't accept as many element as INNER JOIN.